# Derivatives of functions of two variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

Suppose we have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ given and say that $$ \frac{df(x,y)}{dx}=0 $$ then of course this means that f is constant with respect to x but does that mean that f is just a constant function?

Comment: The equation implies that if we hold $y$ constant at some number (say, $y=2$), then the function $f(x, 2)$ is constant in $x$. Overall, the function $f(x,y)$ can still vary with $y$.

Answer (score 0):

No. Consider $f(x,y) = y^2+\pi$. Clearly,
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
 = \frac{\partial y^2}{\partial x} + 0
 = 0
$$
since $y$ is also constant with respect to $x$.

Comment: What is the expression for df/dx in this case? Surely it's not 0

Comment: @Ben it certainly is. You hold $y$ constant when you differentiate in $x$.

Comment: @Ben of course it is zero. see update

Answer (score 0):

No. Take 
$$
f(x,y)=y
$$
This tells you nothing about how the function changes along the $y$ axis.